# Backus-Naur form of a token that begins and ends with double quotes

Tags: parsing, bnf

Is it possible to write a Backus-Naur form description of a token that:

- starts with double quotes
- ends with double quotes
- can contain inner
  double quotes

?

For example I have programming construct called MESSAGE that can look like:

MESSAGE "She said "Hello" to him"

Is that possible to describe with an LL(1) Backus-Naur form?

Edits:  let's assume that I'm parsing by simply iterating over each character, one at a time, with one lookahead pointer.

The input string is the whole thing, including MESSAGE.

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough information about what you're trying to do to get a definitive answer. Is `MESSAGE` part of the input? Can a MESSAGE span multiple lines? What are you parsing, and how?

Comment: How do you know where the MESSAGE ends? iow, why.is your example not two MESSAGEs with a word Hello between them?

Comment: MESSAGE is part of the input, but I already know how to specify that part in BNF.  Let's assume it can span multiple lines (I'm doing research to find out if that's true or not because if it can't then I can just parse til the newline). I'll update the question the make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might do the trick (Sorry for the syntax. It's a while ago, that I worked with BNF).

```
message : MESSAGE message_text
message_text : " inner_message " | message_text inner_message " inner_message "
inner_message : [a-z0-9...]+
```

Your example `MESSAGE "She said "Hello" to him"`
should be interpreted in two steps: First, the second form of `message_text` gets the `hello " to him"` and than, secondly, the first form of `message_text` gets `"She said "`.

`inner_message` must contain all possible characters and spaces.

As mentioned in the comments, the 'magic'  lies in the second definition of `message_text`. As BNF has no concept of loops or if's, recursion is the only way to describe repetitions. One just need to ensure, that the syntax does not get ambiguous, means that for each possible input only one valid path exists (or none, which declares an error). The above syntax should work except for empty middle strings like in `" he replied with "" silence"`.

Comment: Interesting.  The second option for message text is hard for me to interpret.  Is that where the magic lies?  Would you mind trying to explain it conversationally?

Comment: I triedi n the answer. Lets see if I can answer any other specific question.

Comment: Ah I see.  I can understand it now by assuming that the first option is the base case of the recursion.  So what do you think about:  message_text : " inner_message " | " [message_text]+ "    That would work, right?

Comment: If BNF would allow lops like regular expressions. BNF is extremely basic at this point